# how to access the header and data which is send with the url in django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

This below code calls the django url with the data and the header.
'''

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $http({
                url: servicesUrl + "testapi/",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    reportStandardName: moduleName,
                    moduleKey,
                    reportFormat,
                    intervalFromDays,
                    intervalToDays,
                    fromReportTime: moment(fromReportTime, "HH:mm:ss").format('HH:mm:ssZZ'),
                    toReportTime: moment(toReportTime, "HH:mm:ss").format('HH:mm:ssZZ'),
                    reportID,
                    phononUUID,
                    attemptID,
                    requestID,
                    queueIds,
                    flowIds,
                    callStatus,

                    sourceOfRequest: "API",
                    priority: 1,
                    reportTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
                }
```

'''
and below is the django urls file code.
'''

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^testapi/', views.getResponse)
]
```

'''
so how to access the header and the data send with the URL?

Comment: Have you tried `request.headers` and `request.data`?

Comment: No sir. Will this be in request?

Comment: Yup it will indeed